# ftp_nb_put fails without proper reason

Tags: php, ftp

I am using a script that upload two large files to a remote server.
When I test this it uploads a single file,the script executes for some more time,and finally fails.But when my client executes the same script (He is the server owner also),the script upload both file after a gap of 5 minutes of the first file upload.I can't understand what is the problem is? I think it must be problem of wired settings of client's ftp server.

```
            <?php               
            $host = '[HOST]';
            $username = '[USERNAME]';
            $password = '[PASSWORD]';
            $remotepath = '[SERVER DESTINATION FOLDER]';

            $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($host);
            @$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $username, $password);
            ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
            if($login){
                $file_array = array('IMG_4852.CR2','IMG_4839.CR2'); 
                foreach($file_array as $file){      
                    echo 'Uploading file '.$file.'<br/>';
                    $ret = ftp_nb_put($ftp_conn, $remotepath.$file, dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$file, FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);

                    while($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {
                        $ret = ftp_nb_continue($ftp_conn);
                        var_dump($ret) ;echo '<br>';
                    }
                    if ($ret != FTP_FINISHED){
                        echo "Error uploading $file";

                    }

                }   
            }
            ?>
```

Can anyone help me to confirming that it is a ftp server configuration problem or something with my code.

It output lots of 2 and then

```
            Warning: ftp_nb_continue() [function.ftp-nb-continue]: Ok to send data. in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\uploadtoserver.php on line 18

            int 0


            Error uploading IMG_4852.CR2Uploading file IMG_4839.CR2

            Warning: ftp_nb_put() [function.ftp-nb-put]: Transfer complete. in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\uploadtoserver.php on line 15
            Error uploading IMG_4839.CR2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One file size is 9,634,894(this one got uploaded IMG_4852.CR2)

Another file size is 10,653,215(this one not uploaded IMG_4839.CR2)